# Putting unstructured (but regular) cloudpoint back to rectangular array

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, language-agnostic, point-clouds

In a project I am working, some legacy files have saved a rectangular grid as an unstructured 3D point list.

The data represents a "2.5D" mesh, where I have a Z value for a given X,Y value. Since data represents rows and columns, there are a lot of repeated X values (same row) and Y values (same column), but the file does not contain row and column structure, only a flat, sparse list of points.

```
<Point y="1.1102230246252e-016" x="4.4408920985006e-016" z="5.5511151231258e-017">
</Point>
<Point y="0.53695478988409" x="-4.3493741810578" z="0.003063497733423">
</Point>
<Point y="-3.5908575428897" x="0.17408770285142" z="2.1641997610194">
</Point>
<Point y="54.934490992261" x="0.25424397819361" z="1.5580262767693">
</Point>
<Point y="-0.53695478988409" x="4.3493741810578" z="-0.0030634977334228">
</Point>
```

(it is not possible to see in this sample, but if you take one given coordinate, you'd supposedly find many other points with the same coordinate in each dataset)

If I create a scatterplot of the data in xy plane, coloring Z value, this is what I have (it's a human back surface):

[image]

The problem is that, althoug we can "see" the regular structure, it is not present in the point list, and I cannot access points by index, or take a square (3x3) slice around the vicinity of a point.

So, what I need is a way to convert this point list into a bidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You might [project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model) each point to the image plane. Then you should get unique (u,v) coordinates and you can structure your data according to them. Of course you'd have to know the focal length of the device the data was recorded with.